# OCAML how works an 'in'

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I would like to ask You abuot key word 'in'. What is destination of it ? When we use it ?
What does it do ? 
Is there any recommended way to use it ? What about efficiency ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

The keyword `in` is used as part of the `let <binding> in <expression>` syntax.

> When we use it ?

We use it whenever we use a `let` expression.

> What does it do ?

It separates the binding from the expression in which the binding will hold.

> Is there any recommended way to use it ?

The recommended way to use it is as part of a let expression, between the binding and the expression. There is no other way to use it.

> What about efficiency ?

Its function is merely syntactically. Therefore it has no bearing on efficiency.

Comment: The answer would be easier to understand if it made clear that “binding” and “expression” are nonterminals in “let binding in expression”.

Answer (score 0):

Simply say, `in` is to tell the "range" or "domain" of a binding.

```
let x = 5 in
let y = x * x in
x * y
```

The first `in` tells `x=5` is effective in the following `let y = x * x in x * y`, the second `in` tells that `y = x * x` is effective in `x*y`